# Prove Logistic sequence is convergent when $2<k\le3$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Let $0<x_1<1$, $x_{n+1}=kx_n(1-x_n)$ be Logistic sequence. If $2<k\le3$, how to prove the sequence always converges to $1-1/k$?

Edit: I need a direct proof in calculus without using any result from dynamic system.

Answer (score 0):

The fixed points are solutions to $$x=kx(1-x)$$ which are $x=0$ and $x=1-1/k$

We need to show that the fixed point $1-1/k$ is an attractor for $2<k<3$

We take derivative of $f(x)=kx(1-x)$ and show that for the given value of the fixed point $|f'(x)|<1$

Note that $|f'(1-1/k)| = |k-2|$ which is less than $1$ for $2<k<3$

Comment: But the claimed range of convergence is $2<k\color{blue}{\le 3}$.

Comment: Could you give a direct proof in calculus without using any result from dynamic system?

Comment: You have to use the mean value theorem to show that the sequence of iterates get closer to the fixed point because the derivative is less than one in absolute value.$$ |f(x)-f(y) |= |f'(c)||x-y|<|x-y|$$

Comment: Even using this, you could only get the result in some neighborhood of $1-1/k$. And you need to show it for **any** $x_1\in(0,1)$. In fact, if $x_1$ is close to $1$, $f(x_1)$ is close to $0$, and we have $|f(x_1)-f(1-1/k)|>|x_1-(1-1/k)|$.